# Реализовать placeholder в UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Доброго времени суток, всем. Я так понимаю, в WPF нет контрола, который будет похож на TextBox и иметь свойство placeholder'а. В WinForms я писал такой контрол, и зайдествовал, помню, WinAPI.
Я так понял, что в WPF задействовать какое-либо низкое API для отображения PlaceHolder'а в TextBox нет необходимости, поэтому сделал следующее:
1. Создал UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PTRCPriceCalculator.InputBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PTRCPriceCalculator"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="40" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <!-- InputBox template -->
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
            <Grid>
                <!-- Inner texbox -->
                <TextBox HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                         VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                         Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                         Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                         FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                         FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                         BorderThickness="0">

                    <!-- Style for the inner textbox -->
                    <TextBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <!-- Standard textbox role -->
                                            <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                                            </Border>

                                            <!-- Place holder -->
                                            <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="false"
                                                       VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                       HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                       FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                                       FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                                       Text="{Binding PlaceHolder, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                                                       Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">

                                                <!-- Place holder style -->
                                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="">
                                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </TextBlock.Style>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </Grid>

                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBox.Style>
                </TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>

</UserControl>
```

В codebehind определил два свойства зависимости:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PlaceHolderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
"PlaceHolder",
typeof( string ),
typeof( InputBox ) );

public string PlaceHolder
{
    get { return (string)GetValue( PlaceHolderProperty ); }
    set { SetValue( PlaceHolderProperty, value ); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
"Text",
typeof( string ),
typeof( InputBox ) );

public string Text
{
    get { return (string)GetValue( TextProperty ); }
    set { SetValue( TextProperty, value ); }
}
```

Все здорово, PlaceHolder появляется. Но я не могу понять, как мне делегировать свойство Text к свойству Text моего TextBox'а, который находится внутри Template моего UserControl'а?
И еще пару незначительных вопросов:
1. Насколько эффективнее/неэффективнее использовать такой способ создания TextBox'а с placeholder'ом по сравнению с WinAPI?
2. Для отображения PlaceHolder'а, как Вы видите, я определил TextBlock, который отображается/не отображается в зависимости от значения Text в TextBox. Суть в том, что, отображение PlaceHolder'а в TextBlock и реального текста в TextBox не совпадают на несколько пикселей, хотя все проверено мной. Даже Border у TextBox'а убрал, все равно не совпадает. Можно ли это исправить, или лучше забить на это?:)

Comment: Не стоит задавать несколько вопросов в одном вопросе. Вот придёт один человек и ответит на первый вопрос, а второй — на второй, какой ответ будете принимать?

Comment: второй ответ не такой значительный, просто мнение людей хотел услышать, можно комментариях:)

Comment: То есть вы просите, чтобы кто то написал вам ответ в комментариях, чтобы вы получили ответ, а тот, кто вам помог, свои баллы не получил? :)

Comment: А зачем вам из совмещать? Если есть текст в текстбоксе, то в текстблоке его нет и наоборот. Можно шрифт текстблока сделать курсивный и серенький, например, естественно они не будут совпадать

Comment: И да, научитесь уже приводить минимальный пример, зачем отвечающему вникать в ваши триггеры и прочие не относящиеся к вопросу вещи? Это только усложняет чтение кода

Comment: @Андрей на сколько можно сократить мой пример? Можно вообще не высылать сюда было всю эту разметку, а просто спросить, как делегировать свойство объявленное в UserControl, к какому нибудь вложенному в Template контролу. Но Вы бы написали, где код и тд...Вас не поймешь:)

Comment: Шикарный ответ вам дали, почему вы его не приняли? Поставьте галочку. :)

Answer (score 7):

Мне кажется, вы делаете избыточно сложно.

Вот, как мне кажется, более простой вариант. Передаём `TextBlock`'у-плейсхолдеру его «хозяина» как `Tag`, и пишем вот такой стиль:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="PlaceholderStyle"
       xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag.Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                     Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Применяем:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="TB"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Placeholder" Tag="{Binding ElementName=TB}"
               Style="{StaticResource PlaceholderStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

Получается:

[image: I'm on duty]

Если вы хотите, чтобы при установке курсора внутрь фокус плейсхолдер пропадал, вам нужен чуть-чуть более сложный код:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Tag.Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Tag.IsKeyboardFocused,
                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <Condition.Value>
                <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
            </Condition.Value>
        </Condition>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

[image: Don't know]

---

Если вы хотите сделать из этого `UserControl`, это тоже несложно. Единственная тонкость — при привязке `TextBox.Text` к свойству `UserControl`'а нужно устанавливать `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.

Итак, заводим стандартный `UserControl`, называем его `InputBox`, и кладём в него dependency property `Text` и `Placeholder`:

```
public partial class InputBox : UserControl
{
    public InputBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region dp string Text
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Text", typeof(string), typeof(InputBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("",
                  FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    #endregion

    #region dp string Placeholder
    public string Placeholder
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PlaceholderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PlaceholderProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PlaceholderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Placeholder", typeof(string), typeof(InputBox), new PropertyMetadata(""));
    #endregion
}
```

Теперь XAML. Можно пойти традиционным путём:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.InputBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                    AncestorType=UserControl}}">
        <TextBox
            Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            Foreground="{Binding Foreground}" Background="{Binding Background}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Placeholder}" Foreground="Gray"
            IsHitTestVisible="False" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="4">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text}" Value="">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Можно переопределить `ControlTemplate`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.InputBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                            AncestorType=UserControl}}">
                <TextBox
                    Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Placeholder}" Name="PH" Visibility="Hidden"
                   IsHitTestVisible="False" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Gray" Margin="4"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="local:InputBox.Text" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="PH"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

Результат одинаковый.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69606/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd--placeholder--usercontrol).

Comment: Не, с `Value="{x:null}"` тоже не работает:(

Comment: @Bretbas: Ну так вы не гадайте, а выясните конкретно, какое там значение.

Comment: Блин, я на самом деле столько вопросов уже задал, что уже запутался.  Мне кажется там не в значении дело, так как, если я определяю внутри `UserControl.Template` всю эту хрень, то все работает, как только хочу вынести это наружу, в контент UserControl'а, то PlaceHolder перестает появляться

Comment: @Bretbas: Окей, а мой пример работает? Скопируйте вместе с объявлениями DependencyProperty выше.