# TextBoxPlaceholder XAML WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Привет всем. Как то я столкнулся с необходимостью сделать placeholder в textbox
на wpf.
Информации на русскоязычном сегменте довольно мало.
В Связи  с этим хочу предложить свой вариант решения данной проблемы.
Реализовано с помощью UserControl

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="Placeholder.TextBoxPlaceholder"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Placeholder"
             Name="Container"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Padding="{Binding ElementName=Container, Path=Padding}"
                 Background="Transparent" Panel.ZIndex="100" 
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderThickness="0"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBox>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Placeholder}" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   Padding="{Binding ElementName=Container, Path=Padding}">

        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

CodeBehind

```
namespace Placeholder
{
    public partial class TextBoxPlaceholder : UserControl
    {
        static private string PlaceholderOldValue = string.Empty;
        public TextBoxPlaceholder()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }




        public string Placeholder
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PlaceholderProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PlaceholderProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PlaceholderProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Placeholder", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxPlaceholder), new PropertyMetadata("", PlaceholderChanged));
        private static void PlaceholderChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            PlaceholderOldValue = e.OldValue.ToString() != string.Empty ? e.OldValue.ToString() : ""; 
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxPlaceholder), new PropertyMetadata("", TextChanged));
        private static void TextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue.ToString().Length > 0)
                d.ClearValue(PlaceholderProperty);
            if (e.NewValue.ToString().Length == 0)
                d.SetValue(PlaceholderProperty, PlaceholderOldValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Также вот для удобства ссылка на github

```
https://github.com/Ascolon/TextBoxPlaceholder
```

Comment: Разве нельзя это сделать стилем? Зачем писать отдельный контрол для этого?

Comment: интересно а как подскажи?

Comment: типа с потерей фокуса и получением фокуса что ли?

Comment: Ты же плейсхолдер делаешь, тут по идее не фокус нужен, а триггер на поле Text

Comment: [Было](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/752394/220553) подобное уже. VladD довольно хорошо расписал.

Comment: ну я пытался сделать похожим на то как сделано в html там при получении фокуса надпись не пропадает.а делать через стили то я не знаю как реализовать это.Хотя я думаю с помощью стилей это вообще не реально что бы надпись была ниже по Z оси

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, примерно это я и имел ввиду - стиль с тригером

Comment: @Санитариум там есть такой вариант

Comment: @EvgeniyZ хм, хотя он там просто текстблок поверх текстбокса положил и стиль блоку дал. Не, я таки думал про стиль для текстбокса с переопределением темплейта, чтобы просто на любой текстбокс указать и добавить ему плейсхолдер

Comment: Что то типа [такого](http://www.techken.in/coding/c-wpf-create-textbox-placeholder-using-xaml-code/)

Comment: лучше оформить в виде самоответа

Comment: `DataContext = this` это плохая идея, т.к. `DataContext` – это публичное свойство, которое кто угодно может изменить, сломав тем самым ваш контрол.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем User Control слишком много лишнего кода. Можно было просто объявить два Dependency Property без callback-ов и установки DataContext, а в разметке привязаться на свойства User Control с помощью `{Binding ..., RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:TextBoxPlaceholder}}`.

Идеологически верно было бы создать наследника TextBox (Custom Control) с новым свойством PlaceholderText и стилем в Generic.xaml, так как вы по сути расширяете стандартный TextBox новым свойством, а не просто группируете несколько отдельных Control-ов вместе (для чего собственно User Control-ы и были созданы, см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247708/custom-vs-user-control).

Но проще всего создать новый стиль для TextBox, в котором в качестве placeholder текста используется стандартное свойство Tag, тем самым избежав написания какого-либо code behind в принципе.

```
<Style x:Key="PlaceholderTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border x:Name="border"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Grid>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock"
                                   Margin="2,0,0,0"
                                   Foreground="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                   IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                   Text="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                   Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                        <Setter TargetName="textBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.56" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF7EB4EA" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF569DE5" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Преимущество стиля в том, что его можно задать стилем по умолчанию для всех TextBox в App.xaml, не изменяя при этом остальную разметку.

Пример использования:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource PlaceholderTextBoxStyle}" Tag="Hello world!" />
```

[image: Demo]