# Привязка свойств в xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Я хочу сделать TextBox с водяный знаком, но не знаю как сделать установку водяного знака через xaml, пытался использовать привязку, но так и не получилось

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestMVVM.WaterTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMVVM"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="noWater" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100 "></TextBox>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Water" IsHitTestVisible="False" Foreground="Gray" Margin="3 1 0 0">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>

                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName= noWater, Path= Text}" Value="">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C# :

```
public partial class WaterTextBox : UserControl
    {
        public string WaterMark { get; set; } = "Some Text"; // показывает, но изменять нельзя
        public WaterTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Water.Text = WaterMark;
        }
    }
```

MainWindow :

```
<Grid>
 <!-- Не изменяется-->
      <local:WaterTextBox WaterMark="Another Text"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/752394/10105? Там вроде полный пример, даже с UserControl'ом. Обратите внимание, как определено свойство `Placeholder`.

Comment: `<TextBox Background="Transparent" ...`