# WPF, Настройка подсказок для TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Начал разбирать WPf. Как мне сделать для каждого TextBox уникальный текст подсказки?
Например что-бы 1 textBox имел значение, присвоенное в Field_1, 2 - Field_2 и 3 к 3 соответственно.
У меня такая схема:

```
    <VisualBrush x:Key="SearchHint" Stretch="None">
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <TextBox Text="Подсказка"/>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
```

Style:

```
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="AdditemTextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SearchHint}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

TextBoxs:

```
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Field_1}" Style="{StaticResource AdditemTextBox}"/>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Field_2}" Style="{StaticResource AdditemTextBox}"/>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Field_3}" Style="{StaticResource AdditemTextBox}"/>
```

Comment: Например, так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/752394/10105

Comment: Идея с Visual Brush по идее хорошая, да.

Comment: @VladD , Спасибо, выручили, работает)

Comment: Пожалуйста! Тогда закрою вопрос как дубликат.