# Не работает Binding WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

У меня есть команда `LogInCommand`:

```
private void OnLogInCommandExecuted(object obj)
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}

private bool CanLogInCommandExecute(object obj) => LoginEntered == "";
```

`LoginEntered` привязано:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource LogEnterStyle}" Text="{Binding LoginEntered, Mode = OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}"/>
```

И всё работает, если не использовать стиль. Если использовать, то кнопка всегда активна:

```
<Style 
TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
x:Key="LogEnterStyle">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Grid>

                <TextBox 
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                    Background="Transparent" 
                    FontSize="30" 
                    x:Name="LoginBox"
                    Foreground="Black" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    TextAlignment="Center"/>

                <TextBlock 
                    Margin="1"
                    Text="Логин"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    Foreground="#909996"
                    IsHitTestVisible="False"
                    FontSize="30">

                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName = LoginBox}" Value="">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>    
                         
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Как это можно исправить? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Что исправить? Какой биндинг не работает? При чем тут команда?

Comment: Скорее всего неправильный шаблон текстбокса, не вижу в нем `PART_ContentHost`, см. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/passwordbox-styles-and-templates

Comment: `Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"` - это односторонний биндинг, OneWay. [пруф](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). Попробуйте `{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}`.

Comment: @aepot не помогло

Comment: Вам верно подметил `АндрейNOP`, у вас неполноценный шаблон контрола, ибо вы вместо `PART_ContentHost` запихнули в него еще `TextBox`, что естественно неправильно. Если вы хотите чтоб был `TextBox`, который подцепит другой `TextBox`, то сделайте свой `UserControl`, в котором делаете `DependencyProperty` и все это привязываете. Ну а вообще, судя по вашему стилю, вы хотите сделать Placeholder, а это делается немного [иначе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/752394/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо

Comment: Вы можете по сути и имеющийся стиль сделать рабочим. Замените внутренний `TextBox` на `<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />`, привязка будет успешно работать. Триггер, который вы подцепляли через имя, заменяйте на `{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox}}`, или что-то аналогичное, чтоб ваш вложенный `TextBlock` перешел на слой выше, взяв там свойство `Text` (`{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}` тоже должен сработать). Но на вашем месте, я бы всеж сделал отдельный контрол.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, помогло