# Текст TextBlock в TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть TextBox

```
<TextBox Name="Логин" Style="{StaticResource LoginTextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding LoginEntered, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Стиль(применяется не только к этому TextBox) -

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox }"
        x:Key="LoginTextBoxStyle" >

        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" >





            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ScrollViewer
                                 x:Name="PART_ContentHost" 
                                 BorderThickness="0"
                                 Background="Transparent" 
                                 TextElement.Foreground="Black" 
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                />
                        <TextBlock 
                             Margin="1"
                             Text="{TemplateBinding Name}"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                             Background="Transparent"
                        Foreground="#909996"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        FontSize="30"
                        >
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>

                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox}}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>

                                        </DataTrigger>

                                        <MultiDataTrigger>

                                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox}}" Value="False"/>
                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox}}" Value=""/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                                            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>

                                        </MultiDataTrigger>



                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>

                        </TextBlock>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>

        </Setter>


    </Style>
```

На данный момент текст TextBlock задается именем TextBox. Можно ли как-нибудь по-другому задавать текст, чтобы не пришлось для каждого TextBox делать отдельный стил? Извиняюсь, если вопрос глупый.

Comment: Почему для каждого `TextBox` должен быть отдельный стиль? Зачем привязка к `Name`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ привязка к Name потому, что не придумал, как по другому задавать текст TextBlock. Я имел ввиду, что не хочу, чтобы пришлось для каждого TextBox задавать стиль.

Comment: `не придумал, как по другому задавать текст TextBlock.` - а зачем ему задавать текст? У вас помню был вопрос про плейсхолдер, там ок, идет один контрол, при состоянии свойства меняем видимость текста, ок, текст статичен. Но сейчас у вас два контрола в одном, и вы пытаетесь сделать два свойства для них. Вам не кажется, что вы уже превысили рамки "Стилей" и перешли на уровень "UserControl"? `не хочу, чтобы пришлось для каждого TextBox задавать стиль` - я и спрашиваю, почему вам нужно задавать? Что вы хотите в конечном итоге то?

Comment: Посмотрите [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/892926/220553), мне кажется, данный ответ решит все ваши проблемы. Если нет, то тогда уж давайте подробней описывайте, что и как вы хотите получить, ибо сейчас мне ваши действия кажутся странными и нелогичными.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ постараюсь более четко описать то, что мне нужно. У меня есть два TextBox, которые должны выглядеть идентично, единственное отличие в них - текст, который показывается до того момента, как я начинаю ввод текста. Мне не нужно, чтобы этот текст менялся со временем. Я пытаюсь понять, как мне задать разный текст для разных TextBox так, чтобы не пришлось создавать два различных стиля с единственным отличием в этот самом тексте(TextBlock).

Comment: Интересно, а вы читаете вообще и вникаете в то, что вам говорят? Я в вашем [первом же](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1275646#comment2246879_1275646) вопросе давал ссылку на решение, где подробно описывается как сделать плейсхолдер с указанием текста извне, как через стиль (считаю костылем), так и через `UserControl`. Не уж то это не решает поставленную вами задачу?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ читаю, просто хотел сделать это без UserControl, и что такое плейсхолдер я не до конца понял, но если по-другому сделать никак, то буду пытаться сделать так, как вы написали.

Comment: Placeholder - дословный перевод "заполнитель" / "заменитель". Обычно так обозначают элемент (текст), который появляется в тот момент, когда поле для ввода пустое, и пропадает тогда, когда в поле начинают вводить текст. Такое [поведение](https://webformyself.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/66/1.gif) зовется Placeholder'ом. Знакомо? `если по-другому сделать никак` - вы явно не вникаете в то, что вам пишут... Где я такое сказал? Я вам даже ссылку на ответ привел, где подробно описывается два способа реализации этого, через `Style` и через `UserControl`. С чего вы вдруг взяли `по-другому никак`?...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо за помощь, разобрался наконец