# TextBox после применения стиля не передает значение в базу данных

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

У меня курсовая работа (Я все еще новичок и могу многого не понимать)
Нам дали задание в котором обязательно надо сделать вход и регистрацию с использованием Базы данных но после того как я применил созданный мною стиль значение вводимых данных не передаются в бд (Передается Null). Без стиля все работает.

Вот мой код стиля

```
           x:Key="ModernTextboxLogin">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="20"
                            Background="White">
                            
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle StrokeThickness = "1"/>
                            <TextBox Margin = "40,0,0,0"
                                     
                                     BorderThickness="0"
                                     Background="Transparent"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                     Padding="5"
                                     x:Name="Login"/>
                            <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       Margin="50,0,0,0"
                                       Grid.Column="1">

                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text}" Value="">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                                
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Вот сам TextBox

```
<TextBox Name="txbLogin" Text="Login" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource ModernTextboxLogin}" Margin="78,1,0,7" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" FontFamily="Alice" FontSize="16"/>
```

Comment: Сделали стиль для `TextBox`, который содержит в себе еще один `TextBox`, не кажется странным? Если вы хотите редактировать стандартный контрол, то добавьте его без стилей, в дизайнере студии ПКМ по нему, там будет пункт "Редактировать шаблон" или что-то в этом духе, там выбирайте "Копию", после чего вам сделает копию шаблона, который и правьте, либо на его основе делайте свой. Ну, либо идите в [документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates) и смотрите как и что сделано по стандарту.

Comment: Я не нашел подобного способа в интернете и делал как мог щас попробую посмотреть
А возможно ли передать значение имени TextBox в стиль или сделать так чтобы он присваивался в TextBox внутри style когда применяешь стиль к конкретному TextBox? 
(Я понимаю что это усложнение но мне просто интересно возможно ли так сделать)

Comment: `TemplateBinding` - односторонняя привязка. Надо `{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}` https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension читайте документацию. Но это конечно не отменяет комментариев выше.

Comment: Я попробовал двух стотонную привязку и у меня все ровно передает Null
Я думаю что я скорее всего что то не понимаю...
Имеет смысл вообще пытаться провернуть эту схему или это потребует слишком много времени
Просто завтра уже сдавать курсовую...

Comment: Непонятно, какого эффекта вы хотели добиться такой разметкой. Задачу держите в секрете.

Comment: Я хотел добиться скругления краев в у TextBox
Но на прямую как это сделать я не нашел потому нашел англо язычный гайд где он создает WPF страницу
И переделал то что собрал он, визуальный эффект тот который нужен но проблема уже описана выше

Comment: Только в краях дело или ещё в чем-то?

Comment: Хм... В основном да, но в последствии я добавил еще текст который исчезает при нажатии на TextBox
(Не понимаю как добавить Изображения чтобы показать визуально а не описывать текстом)

Comment: [Скругление краев](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31556325/6808809), [текст который исчезает (зовется Placeholder](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/752394/220553)).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Щас попробую сделать

Comment: У PasswordBox получится также округлить края ?

Comment: Нет, там надо стиль переписывать как я сказал выше, получите что-то по типу [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68819285/6808809).