# WPF — добавление водяного знака в собственное текстовое поле PasswordBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, password, watermark

Как сделать так чтобы у passwordBox был водиной текст Password:
У меня уже есть такое код для TextBox но для  passwordBox не получаеться сделать

```
        <Style x:Key="MyWaterMarkStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="#FF7D8683" BorderThickness="1"/>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <Label Margin="1,0,0,0" x:Name="WaterMarkLabel" Content="{TemplateBinding Tag}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="Orange" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="13"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Text" Value=""/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="WaterMarkLabel" Value="Visible"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DimGray"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource MyWaterMarkStyle}" Tag="Username:" 
            x:Name="txtUsername" Height="25" Width="180" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
 <PasswordBox x:Name="txtPassword" Height="25" Width="180" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607066/wpf-watermark-passwordbox-from-watermark-textbox

Comment: Это зовется "плейсхолдер". Водяной знак (или варермарк) - это некий текст/лого, нанесенный, например, на фото, таким образом вы немного защищаете изображение от копирования и распространения, а также рекламируете себя/свой брент. Плейсхолдер - это именно текст-подсказка, который есть в текстовом поле, и исчезает/сдвигается при фокусе элемента. У нас на SO есть [отличный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/752394/220553) того, как реализовать подобное, думаю не особо составит труда подправить это для `PasswordBox`.

Comment: Мне нужно для  PasswordBox чтобы при воде были *****, а с TextBox у меня все работает